# how make abstract restfull basic with Spring mvc Controller for angular js?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

Sorry I'm starting on the site.
How can I make a controller Generic restfull post JSON? 
My DAOS and services work perfectly.
DAOS already are ready more do not know where to start ..!

I tried to do so:

```
public class AbstractControllerCrud<T extends IDomainObject> {

    protected IGenericService<T> service;

    public AbstractControllerCrud(IGenericService<T> service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected
    @ResponseBody
    List<T> getAll() {
        List<T> listaGenerica = new ArrayList<>();
        listaGenerica = service.getBeans();
        return listaGenerica;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected
    @ResponseBody
    T get(@PathVariable int id) {
        Long idRequest = (long) id;
        T retorno = this.service.getObjeto(idRequest);
        return retorno;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    protected void delete(@PathVariable int id) {
        Long idRequest = (long) id;
        T T = this.service.getObjeto(idRequest);
        service.deleta(T);
    }
}
```

but it does not work:  error 404;

```
@Controller("/test")
public class TestController extends AbstractControllerCrud<Profissoes> {
    @Autowired
    public TestController(@Qualifier("profissoesServicesImpl") IGenericService<Profissoes> profissaoService) {
        super(profissaoService);
    }
}
```

this works, it does not display 404.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profissoes")
public class ProfissoesController {

    @Autowired
    private IProfissoesService profissaoServ;

    @RequestMapping(value = "all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    List<Profissoes> getProfissoes() {
        List<Profissoes> listaProfissoes = new ArrayList<>();
        listaProfissoes = profissaoServ.getBeans();
        return listaProfissoes;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Profissoes get(@PathVariable int id) {
        Long idRequest = (long) id;
        Profissoes profissoes = this.profissaoServ.getObjeto(idRequest);
        return profissoes;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void delete(@PathVariable int id) {
        Long idRequest = (long) id;
        Profissoes profissao = this.profissaoServ.getObjeto(idRequest);
        profissaoServ.deleta(profissao);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi guys I Need Generic Controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angulrjs controller:

```
yourAppName.controller('myController' , [$http , $scope , function($http , $scope)
{
 var paramValue = [];
 paramValue['par'] = $scope.someValue;
$http.get('rest/getdata' , {params : paramValue}).success(function(data)
{
   $scope.myData = data;

}).error(function(data)
{
   console.log('error occured');

});

}]);
```

spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/getdata",method = RequestMethod.GET , params = "par")  
public @ResponseBody  
List<Profissoes> getProfissoes(@RequestMapping("par") long value)  {
        System.out.println("Value "+value);
        // use it further the way u want
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I think u want make requests from angular like:
.../all?itemType=Project
.../all?itemType=User
and so on...
Why not then:

```
public @ResponseBody List<? extends IItem> getAll(@RequestParam String itemType) {
    IService<? extends IItem> service = ServiceFactory.get(itemType);
    // or
    IService<? extends IItem> service = context.getBean(itemType);
    return service.getAll();
}
```

Anyway, unlikely that spring can guess object type from json...